# PID using Axis-Angle or Rotation Matrix

Tags: euler-angles, rotational-matrices, imu, mpu6050

I went through euler angles and I understood it is prone to Gimbal locks at certain angles. This worries me and might cause failure in my robot.

I learned that Axis-Angle and Rotation Matrices are safe. is there anyway to to build a PID controller using them?

I have MPU-6050 and I have results for Axis-Angle or Quateruions

Euler angles cause problem at certain angles.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with euler angles is that they have singularities at certain orientations. You can choose different order of transformations and design your system such that the gimball lock appears in an orienation that will practically never occur.

The transformation matrix has 9 unknowns. Often it is expressed as a function of euler angles, but then we get back to euler angles.

I think your best shot is to try to control the quaternion.

Comment: do you know how to control it using quaternion?